# No Zoom and Google Meet on Android 7/8 TV

Tags: android-tv, webcam

I have Sony TV X82E 2017 model. Today [MiTV Webcam](https://store.mi.com/in/item/3212500004) got launched. It says in the specs that the webcam supports Android 8 and above which I think my TV has.

But when I tried to install Google Meet and Zoom from the Google Play TV store, it said that this was not available for this device. So there's no Google Meet and Zoom for my Android TV, then there is no point in buying this webcam.

Is there ***any*** way to get Google Meet and Zoom on my Android TV?

Comment: Have you tried to side-load those apps onto your TV? The Zoom app defines in it's AndroidManifest.xml that it uses the camera but it also says that a camera is not required (-> hence it is optional). A lot of apps are not available via Play Store because their developer simply have not tested it for AndroidTV compatibility.

Comment: Google Meet is a Google product. Is there a reason why Google Meet isn't available for the TV ?